# AngularJS: Calling a directive function from a controller the right way

Tags: angularjs

I have two scenarios:

1. A function defined in a controller is called from a directive ([see plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8363ZkIJP1ii7aIrfrM7?p=preview)).

The directive includes a '&' scope restriction to relate the controller and directive functions. If you click on the text, the element click event is triggered in the directive and the controller function is called. $scope.$apply() is used to notify AngularJS of the click event and refresh the value of var on the screen.

2. A function defined in a directive is called from a controller ([see plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/quVoBuKNVHx3BNiLKbyj?p=preview)).

The directive doesn't have any scope restriction, meaning that `$scope` in the controller and `scope` in the directive are shared. I defined  `func1()` in the directive that can be called from the controller (try clicking on the text), however it seems intrusive as the controller needs to know the name of the function.

Is there a way to define `func1()` in such a way that the function name is declared in the directive div, similar to scenario 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options are possible and acceptable depending on how you are building the component.

**Option 1** - Controllers should register listeners/callbacks and set attributes on directives (when using isolated scope - which i recommend). Controllers should not call a directives function but instead should change an attribute that has been bound on the directive. The directive if setup correctly should be watching this attribute and update accordingly.

Directives should not know who their controllers are in my opinion, it promotes decoupled code. Instead, controllers should be setting callback functions that directives can invoke at the appropriate time (i.e. letting the controller know something was clicked, selected, deleted, swiped, etc...)

**Option 2** - Is acceptable to me when you are building a web component that provides the structure and behavioral logic but does not define the actual individual components UI (not including a possible skeleton UI). For example a list directive. The individual list may not be defined in the directive but "plugged in" for each context or use, giving us a more modular and reusable component. It does require us to know some things about the directive. It also requires that we modify the transclusion function to use the directives scope on the transcluded content instead of the original controllers scope. For an example you can checkout a list component I made as an example to this point.

http://github.com/Spidy88/ng-web-components

A snippet of text from this [html page](https://github.com/Spidy88/ng-web-components/blob/master/app/phone/emailList.html). The sf-list directive is an isolated scope directive that defines a lists behavior. However we can still define what each individual list item looks like with modified transclusion. It relies on us to call `selectItem` though in order to trigger selection behavior on the list.

```
<sf-list items="ctrl.emails" listener="ctrl.adapter">
    <div class="list-item email" ng-click="selectItem(item)" ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
        <div class="from">{{ item.from }}:</div>
        <div class="subject">{{ item.subject }}</div>
    </div>
</sf-list>
```

Comment: Thanks Spidy. You say `instead should change an attribute that has been bound on the directive` can you give an example of an attribute that when changed triggers a function call?

Comment: For this specific example of "clicking" I can't think of how or why you'd change an attribute to trigger a function call. Look at my updated last paragraph, I think that better answers what you are trying to do in Option 2.